# How to store arbitrary data in Html tags within each loop?

Tags: jquery

I want to store data inside Li for displaying it when it's being clicked. 
I've used Data attribute but it's store only the type...rather then the object itself ...so it's doing something like

```
  <li data="[object][object]">
```

Here is what i've done so far :

```js
var data_obj = [{
  name: "foo",
  age: 33
}, {
  name: "goo",
  age: 34
}];

var tmp = '<ul id="list">';
var count = 0;

$.each(data_obj, function() {

  count++;
  tmp += '<li data="' + this + '">' + count + '</li>';
});

$('#res').html(tmp + '</ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

My goal is to be able to get the Li's data when being clicked....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating your html, build it up and add separate `data` elements for each key/value in your data:

```js
var data_obj = [{
  name: "foo",
  age: 33
}, {
  name: "goo",
  age: 34
}];

var count = 0;
var lis = [];
$.each(data_obj, function() {

   var $li = $('<li />');
   $.each(this, function(k,v){
      $li.data(k,v);
   })
  count++;
  $li.text(count)
  lis.push($li)
});

$('#res').append($('<ul>').append(lis))
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).data('name') + ":" + $(this).data('age'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `[object][object]` because that's what javascript does when it tries to convert an object to a string. And when you do `"str" + obj + "str"`, `obj` is converted to string.

You could also use `JSON.stringify`, but jQuery has a better way:

You can benefit from jQuery's [**`.data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function, and jQuery's implementation of element creation.

Try this instead:

```js
var data_obj = [{
  name: "foo",
  age: 33
}, {
  name: "goo",
  age: 34
}];

var $ul = $('<ul/>', {
  id: 'list'
});

var count = 0;

$.each(data_obj, function() {

  count++;
  var $li = $("<li/>", {
    text: count
  });
  $li.data('obj', this);
  $ul.append($li);
});

$('#res').append($ul);

//You can use this to retrieve data on click:

$("#res").on('click', 'li', function(){
  var data = $(this).data('obj');
  alert(data.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the `data()` method to store an object within jQuery's data cache. You will however need to re-arrange your logic slightly though, in order to retain the references to the created elements, something like this:

```js
var data_obj = [{
  name: "foo",
  age: 33
}, {
  name: "goo",
  age: 34
}];

var elements = data_obj.map(function(obj, i) {
  return $(`<li>${i + 1}</li>`).data('obj', obj);  
});

$('<ul id="list" />').appendTo('#res').append(elements);

// for testing only...
$('#res').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('obj'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in li element by converting it to string with JSON.stringify().

```
 var data_obj = [{
      name: "foo",
      age: 33
    }, {
      name: "goo",
      age: 34
    }];

    var tmp = '<ul id="list">';
    var count = 0;

    $.each(data_obj, function() {

      count++;
      tmp += '<li data="' + JSON.stringify(this) + '">' + count + '</li>';
    });

    $('#res').html(tmp + '</ul>');
```